# Python multiprocessing pool OSError: Too many files open

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have to check how much time `do_something()` takes in total for a pair of lists containing 30k elements. Below is my code

```
def run(a, b, data):
    p = datetime.datetime.now()
    val = do_something(a, b, data[0], data[1])
    q = datetime.datetime.now()
    res = (q - p).microseconds
    return res
```

Next, I call this using the following code:

```
func = functools.partial(run, a, b)

x = np.linspace(500, 1000, 30000).tolist()
y = np.linspace(20, 500, 30000).tolist()

data = zip(x, y)

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
    d = pool.map(func, data)
res = sum(d)
```

Whenever I run this, I keep getting `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ulimit -u 2048` to raise the process limit.

Use `ulimit -a` to check the current limits.

Comment: Current limit was around 325k. Tried this and raised limit to 10 million, still the same error at the same time.

Comment: Use timeout or gc.collect() to make sure the processes are garbage collected. Looks like it's saving the proc file descriptors which is overflowing. Also use `pool.join()` after map.