# Multiprocess and Multiprocessing with no file IO: OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python, multiprocessing, multiprocess

**Summary**:

I'm trying to use multiprocess and multiprocessing to parallelise work with the following attributes:

- Shared datastructure
- Multiple arguments passed to a function
- Setting number of processes based on current system

**Errors**:

My approach works for a small amount of work but fails with the following on larger tasks:

`OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`

**Solutions tried**

Running on a macOS Catalina system, `ulimit -n` gives `1024` within Pycharm.

Is there a way to avoid having to change `ulimit`? I want to avoid this as the code will ideally work out of the box for various sytems.

I've seen in related questions like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65298058/python-multiprocessing-pool-oserror-too-many-files-open) that recommend using .join and gc.collect in the comments, other threads recommend closing any opened files but I do not access files in my code.

```
import gc
import time

import numpy as np

from math import pi
from multiprocess import Process, Manager
from multiprocessing import Semaphore, cpu_count

def do_work(element, shared_array, sema):
    shared_array.append(pi*element)
    gc.collect()
    sema.release()

# example_ar = np.arange(1, 1000) # works
example_ar = np.arange(1, 10000) # fails

# Parallel code
start = time.time()
# Instantiate a manager object and a share a datastructure
manager = Manager()
shared_ar = manager.list()
# Create semaphores linked to physical cores on a system (1/2 of reported cpu_count)
sema = Semaphore(cpu_count()//2)
job = []
# Loop over every element and start a job
for e in example_ar:
    sema.acquire()
    p = Process(target=do_work, args=(e, shared_ar, sema))
    job.append(p)
    p.start()
_ = [p.join() for p in job]
end_par = time.time()

# Serial code equivalent
single_ar = []
for e in example_ar:
    single_ar.append(pi*e)
end_single = time.time()

print(f'Parallel work took {end_par-start} seconds, result={sum(list(shared_ar))}')
print(f'Serial work took {end_single-end_par} seconds, result={sum(single_ar)}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to avoid changing the ulimit is to make sure that your process pool size does not increase beyond 1024.  That's why 1000 works and 10000 fails.

Here's an example of managing the processes with a Pool which will ensure you don't go above the ceiling of your ulimit value:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction

> other threads recommend closing any opened files but I do not access
> files in my code

You don't have files open, but your processes are opening file descriptors which is what the OS is seeing here.

Comment: Does using semaphores in my code not limit the number of processes spawned? Thanks for the clarification on file descriptors.

Comment: Nope, semaphores can help with [synchronization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Semaphore), e.g. helping to lock resources for timing purposes but they don't create a limit on number of processes created.

Comment: I see, I had assumed that blocking and releasing would limit the number of processes created to those specified in the Semaphore instantiation. Regarding the use of Pool can you see an alternative to re-writing my code with starmap to pass the multiple arguments I need?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442981/1399491)? it uses a context manager to manage the pool.  If you get stuck with that method, you should try creating a new question

Comment: The merge_names_unpack is an intermediary that unpacks arguments if you want to pass them

Comment: I have not, I will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: What is the relation between 5 and 1024?

Answer (score 1):

Check limit on number of file descriptors. I changed my ulimit to `4096` from `1024` and it worked.
Check:

```
ulimit -n
```

For me it was `1024`, and I updated it to `4096` and it worked.

```
ulimit -n 4096
```